# Iterating a list of json object?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I have to iterate over a list of json object ("local_properties") and check in each object if  "is_built_in"= false or not. How I am supposed to do that. I am getting the below json as a response of GET API.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "local_properties": [
    {
      "id": 1000221,
      "name": "RSCD_DIR",
      "data_type": "String",
      "default_value_source": "SystemObject/local",
      "value": "/C/PROGRA~1//",
      "is_built_in": true,
      "is_deprecated": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1000221,
      "name": "RSCD_DIR",
      "data_type": "String",
      "default_value_source": "SystemObject/local",
      "value": "/C/PROGRA~1//",
      "is_built_in": false,
      "is_deprecated": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1000221,
      "name": "RSCD_DIR",
      "data_type": "String",
      "default_value_source": "SystemObject/local",
      "value": "/C/PROGRA/",
      "is_built_in": true,
      "is_deprecated": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What part do you have troubles with?

Comment: Integer id = TestUtil.testEnvData.getBlpackages().get(0).get("id");;
String url = TestUtil.blPackagesUrl + "/" + id;
 Response body = TestUtil.getResponseOfAPI(url, headerForSessionId);
 List local_properties= body.jsonPath().getList("local_properties");
        for (Object object : local_properties) {
         System.out.println("Output : "+object.toString());

Comment: Use the `edit` button to add the code to the question.

Comment: Deserialize JSON using Jackson or GSON and iterate through `local_properties` array

Comment: I am not able to iterate over every object and not able to get "is_built_in" key.

Comment: use [Json-Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Answer (score 2):

Consider desiarlizing your response using Jackson and then you will be able to iterate through 'local_properties' and perform a given action when 'is_built_in' is true. The following snippet shows one way of achieving this, assuming you will be able to deserialise your json into Jacksons JsonNode.

```
String sampleJson = "{\n" +
                "  \"id\": 1,\n" +
                "  \"local_properties\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 1000221,\n" +
                "      \"name\": \"RSCD_DIR\",\n" +
                "      \"data_type\": \"String\",\n" +
                "      \"default_value_source\": \"SystemObject/local\",\n" +
                "      \"value\": \"/C/PROGRA~1/BMCSOF~1/BLADEL~1/rscd/\",\n" +
                "      \"is_built_in\": true,\n" +
                "      \"is_deprecated\": true\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 1000221,\n" +
                "      \"name\": \"RSCD_DIR\",\n" +
                "      \"data_type\": \"String\",\n" +
                "      \"default_value_source\": \"SystemObject/local\",\n" +
                "      \"value\": \"/C/PROGRA~1/BMCSOF~1/BLADEL~1/rscd/\",\n" +
                "      \"is_built_in\": false,\n" +
                "      \"is_deprecated\": true\n" +
                "    }]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode json = mapper.readValue(sampleJson, JsonNode.class);
        json.get("local_properties").elements().forEachRemaining(node -> {
            if (node.get("is_built_in").asBoolean()) {
                //Do Something when is_built_in is true
            }
        });
```